# wordpress wp-admin redirects to my-account page

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

When I try to reach admin panel by wp-admin, asking me username and password but afterwords redirects me to my-account page and cannot go to admin panel. Is there anyone help on this item?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the .htaccess file via FTP on the server for the offending redirect rule.

Otherwse, it is likely a plugin causing the redirect, try logging into the server via FTP and renaming the plugin folder, then create a new plugin folder and sequentially add each plugin back into the new folder, and test, until you find the culprit.